# One Month Rails - invalid email or password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I took about a week off from working on "Mattan Griffel's One Month Rails." For some reason when I returned, either the password or the email was invalid for my localhost:3000. Mattan led us through the process of signing up on our localhost page with the `email: user@example.com` and `password: foobar`, but it won't work for me now. Could this be my fault with a syntax error in sublime, or what could be the problem?

This is what the Terminal reads when it doesn't go through:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-06 13:53:44 -0600
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8rUKRPLsIttdHhv49tgT8KcvKbjT9mMP/lP5M/N8uPQ=", "user"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'user@example.com' LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this worked before, but it's not anymore, I'm guessing that you're probably just using the wrong password.

Try the following to reset your password in the Rails console:

```
User.find_by_email('user@example.com').update_attribute(:password, 'your_new_password')
```

Then, try logging back in and see what happens.

Comment: Ok so I tried to follow these instructions and look up exactly what the rails console is, but I am having trouble following what you suggested. if you can't tell, coding isn't exactly my forte and i'm in the beginning stages of learning, but how exactly do i use that syntax command or whatever it is to reset my password? i appreciate the help!

Comment: The Rails console is a tool that loads your full Rails environment and makes it available via command line. Because you can manipulate your models by hand, it comes in very handy for debugging. Access it from your project root by typing `rails console` (or `rails c` for short). You'll be displayed a prompt from which you can reset your user password by entering the above statement. Once you've run the statement, return to your Rails app (running in your web server) and try logging in again.