# My login over localhost wont work with my heroku site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, authentication

I am having the same problem as another guy who posted this question about two months ago, but I wasn't able to figure out the solution based on the answers that people gave him. I am a total newb to all this coding stuff, and it's getting really tricky for me. Can anyone maybe help lead me in a step by step process of how to sync your local host user@example.com with your heroku one. I have already done the commands for it all, but I think it's is something with the database or something I don't know. Thank you very much! I really appreciate the help.

Comment: It seems you remain a bit unfamiliar with how Stack Overflow works. This site is for question-and-answer... not for step-by-step instructions. Although you might receive answers to such questions, you're better off positing a specific question, accompanied by details of what you've already tried. Also, the reputation system is _crucial_ in making SO work effectively. If an answer addresses your question, you should accept it. Please return to the following answer and accept it if it's correct, as you've indicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971342/#16971486

Comment: ya for sure. alright i'll try and do a little more research. thanks man.

Comment: You've commented that the answer for another question is correct. Can you accept the answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971342/#16971486

Answer (score 0):

When you `git push heroku master` to Heroku you are just uploading the code and db structure, not you local db content. If you have a seed.rb file you can run it with `heroku run rake db:setup` to migrate and seed your database. You can also import your db to heroku, here a [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) to do that.

Comment: I really appreciate your help thank you, but for some reason this isn't working for me. I tried to follow the steps of importing the db to heroku and it just wouldn't work. I mean I'm assuming I did it wrong, but ya it just didn't work. I've spent a couple hours trying to figure this out and it's just not budging of me... I really appreciate the help man.